# Eliminate plot values above and below a value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm graphing several points and I want to eliminate all values above and below a given range.

So i've plotted all my points as

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
```

I have two arrays: "magnitude" and "color", and equations of best fit so im plotting as:

```
plt.scatter(magnitude,color)
plt.plot(x,equation)
plt.plot(x,equation +0.5, linestyle =  '--')
plt.plot(x,equation-0.5, linestyle = '--')
```

where x is just some linspace.
It gives me a plot that looks like this:
[image]

which is exactly what I want, but now I want to remove all of the points above and below the red dotted lines (which are equation +0.5, and equation -0.5) but I really have no clue how to do this.  Tips?

Comment: Is speed a large consideration for your result?

Comment: yes. i have 482 plots to do this with.  well over a million data points overall lol

Comment: Do you need to reproject along that axis or can you basically just trim it horizontally as close as possible? One option is to just select only the data you want, potentially by chucking your data into a pandas df and taking a slice over the value range you want. Also, is this hoizontal-ish line you show of a variable nature? Can it range all the way up to vertical? Since it is a best fit I am guessing so.

Comment: i don't need to reproject, just toss all the values above and below the lines.  the'yre linear, but not horizontal

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of indexing and create a mask defining your boundary conditions since your `equation` seems to be a NumPy array as you are performing arithmetic operation (`+0.5`) on it as

```
y1 = equation - 0.5
y2 = equation + 0.5

mask = (color>y1) & (color<y2)

plt.scatter(magnitude[mask], color[mask])
plt.plot(x, equation)
plt.plot(x, y1, linestyle =  '--')
plt.plot(x, y2, linestyle = '--')
```

Comment: this seems like it has potential to work, but my "equation" array is not as long as my color array, so it can't broadcast the elements together

Comment: Then you need to create an equation of straight line for y1 and y2 and then get the indices of values which are between and two lines

Comment: just use the first and the last point to create equation of straight line